# SignatureDoesNotMatch in Amazon API

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-mws

I am using the Amazon API and get this error while updating my stock from my database to Amazon website:

```
Caught Exception: Internal Error
Response Status Code: 0
Error Code:
Error Type:
Request ID:
XML:
```

I read this thread (amazonsellercommunity . com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=2194823) and then get the error explanation:

```
<Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message><Detail/></Error>
```

So I thought my MARKETPLACE_ID, MERCHANT_ID, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY could be wrong. But I checked and these informations are correct.

Actually, I don't understand why this error happens... Before, it worked perfectly and since a couple of days it just crash. And I don't change anything in my code. Strange, isn't it?

Edit :

Here is my section code for signature.

```
define ('DATE_FORMAT', 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
define('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'ABC...'); // My AWS Access Key Id (20 characters)
define('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', 'ABCDEF...'); // My AWS Secret Access Key (40 characters)
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'MyCompany_AmazonMWS');
define('APPLICATION_VERSION', '0.0.1');
define ('MERCHANT_ID', 'XXXXXXX'); // My Merchant ID
define ('MARKETPLACE_ID', 'XXXXXXX'); // My Marketplace ID

$config = array (
'ServiceURL' => "https://mws.amazonservices.fr",
'ProxyHost' => null,
'ProxyPort' => -1,
'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
);

$service = new MarketplaceWebService_Client(
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
$config,
APPLICATION_NAME,
APPLICATION_VERSION
);

$parameters = array (
'Marketplace' => MARKETPLACE_ID,
'Merchant' => MERCHANT_ID,
'FeedType' => '_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_',
'FeedContent' => $feedHandle,
'PurgeAndReplace' => false,
'ContentMd5' => base64_encode(md5(stream_get_contents($feedHandle), true)),
);

// and then I do this:

$request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_SubmitFeedRequest($parameters);
invokeSubmitFeed($service, $request);
```

If you want to see some parts of my code, just ask.

Comment: Try this with the amazon Scratchpad.https://mws.amazonservices.de/scratchpad/index.html

Comment: I am using the scratchpad and still get this same error. I have retyped the keys many times, copy and pasted, but even the scratchpad reports that the signature does not match, not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, the authentication mechanism for Amazon APIs is sensitive to the current date/time on your machine (which is used in the process of signing the request). Check to see if your date/time is set correctly.

Comment: Note that different services have different time tolerances.  For SQS, the tolerance was quite low, while S3 had several minutes of tolerance. Just run chronyd on your box (not NTPD, it doesn't handle VMs well).

Answer (score 1):

For me it was just an error with my web app passing url escaped strings. The special characters weren't like by amazon and this (not so useful) error came up. Make sure your file names have no url escaped characters.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it (on Ubuntu 14.04 Server) using `ntpdate`:

First make sure it is installed:

```
apt-get install ntpdate
```

And then execute:

```
ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: can you explain why this would fix the questioner's problem?

Comment: The clock skew between what the system time is on the machine this code is running and Amazon's server can be enough that Amazon rejects the request because it deems it too old.

You'll get a message though, if that's the case.  Something to the effect of "Request has expired." or the like.  I've seen it, though I don't remember the exact wording.